# 2 divs, side by side that takes 100% of the space

Tags: css, html

I've searched and found many questions and answers here but I just can't get this thing to work.

You can view my HTML and CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/PqjqF/2/

HTML

```
<div id="SearchBox">
    <div id="SearchFieldContainer">
        <input class="SearchField" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
    </div>
    <div id="SearchButtonContainer">
        <a href="#" class="SearchButton">Search</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#SearchBox {
    width: *;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 14px 8px 8px 8px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(92%,#f3f3f3));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f3f3f3 92%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#f3f3f3 92%); /* W3C */
}

#SearchFieldContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#SearchButtonContainer{
   float:left;
}

.SearchField {
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    color: #0a0705;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000,000,000,0.7) 0 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000,000,000,0.7) 0 1px 1px;
    padding:8px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    width:100%;
}

.SearchField:focus {
   background: #fff;
   color: #000000;
}

.SearchButton {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px #8a8a8a;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px #8a8a8a;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #2f3c47), color-stop(1, #0f1011) );
    background-color:#2f3c47;
    -webkit-border-radius:42px;
    border-radius:42px;
    border:1px solid #0d060d;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px 18px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

What I want to have is that the input field will take all the space it has and the search button to be next to it, on the same line.

I tried so many things like hidden overflow and other but it refuses to work :-/

Any help here?

Thanks,
- Shai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your HTML a bit to let `div#SearchButtonContainer` appears before `div#SearchFieldContainer`.
2. Add `margin-right` to `div#SearchFieldContainer` make enough room for the button. Remove its `float: left;` style, then it will spread 100% width by default (with some margin at right);
3. Add `float: right;` to `div#SearchButtonContainer`.

View the modified example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPxDk/2/)

Comment: Thanks! Seem to work (even that it doesn't seem to be the most elegant way around)

Comment: This is note the best method to achieve this layout.  Using margin space to compensate for the width of a nearby floated element isn't exactly best practice.  See my answer for more solid solutions.

Comment: @Michael your solution works because you have specified `80%`, `20%` width for the `div`s, however, that doesn't fit @Shai 's requirements. Normally, the search button should not resize when the `#SearchBox` gets resized.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, just try:

```
#SearchFieldContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#SearchButtonContainer{
   float:left;
   width: 50%;
}
```

So both divs take each 50% of the width = 100% width. Some more work is need for perfect fit, but basically it should work. Remember to "clear" (If you don't know, look for clear:both).

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is that certain things aren't adding up to 100%.  For example the text field itself is set to 100% width but has padding which makes it larger than 100%.  If you wrap the text-field in a border you can see it extends past it's containing div.  There are a few ways to fix this...  Either remove the paddings, calculate the paddings into your total 100% widths, or use the CSS: `box-sizing: border-box;` Which tells the browser to calculate the width including padding and borders.

The same is true for both of your containers.

**I will use the `box-sizing` method I mentioned above first...**

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PqjqF/4/

Here I have added `box-sizing: border-box;` to both of your containers, the text field and button.  I left the borders in place so you can see the edges of your containers. (this is a great technique for debugging your layouts to see where your boxes are)

I have changed width of the containers to 80% and 20% respectively and set the width of the text-field to be 100%.  You could also apply a 100% width to the button to make it fill it's container.

See the [Can I Use It?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) for box-sizing for browser compatibility.

---

**Now a solution without `box-sizing: border-box;`...**

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PqjqF/5/

Here, I have calculated the padding's as a percentage, in this case 1% into the width of the element itself.  So, 1% to padding left and right (top and bottom doesnt matter), and 98% width = 100%.